# Manipulate Windows "Users" group without access to domain?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a C#/WPF application that is used to manipulate local users and groups on a system. We only care about local users and groups, regardless of whether the machine is joined to a domain or not. When we create a user in our application, I want to add the user to the "Users" group. Normally this works fine, but if the machine is domain-joined and NOT connected to the network (e.g. a laptop out of the office), I get "the network path is not found" errors when trying to add a local user to the "Users" group.

I think the reason is because the "Users" group contains domain users, as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

And this is essentially my code:

```
        public static void AddUserToGroup(UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal, string groupName)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
            {
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
                if (group == null)
                {
                    group = CreateLocalWindowsGroup(groupName);
                }
                if (!group.Members.Contains(oUserPrincipal)) // this line throws "network path not found" exception if the machine is domain joined, but can't contact the domain controller
                    group.Members.Add(oUserPrincipal);
                group.Save();
            }
        }
```

I can't figure out how to approach this with the API, but it seems like it should be possible because I can add the exact same user to the same group manually with the "Local Users and Groups" tool with no issues, regardless of network connectivity. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: The script you are running.. are you running it with a domain account or local account? Is the account you are running part of the same domain that the oUserPrincipal is part of?

Comment: I am running it with a domain account. Seems weird, I know, but we are testing the application on domain-joined company PCs. It will be on non-domain joined PCs in production (so this is really only an issue for developers).

Comment: If you are not connected to the network, then you will have this error because group.Members queries the domain to look up the details on the members.

Comment: It makes sense. But is there any way around it? Can I catch the exception somehow and continue to work with just the local members of that group? I actually just got an elaborate try{foreach{}} setup working to read all the local members, but I can't figure out how to add a user. Even the add method throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

This is one reason I don't like using the `AccountManagement` namespace.

The [`GroupPrincipal.Members`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.members) property returns a [`PrincipalCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcollection), which is just a collection of [`Principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal) objects. The actual type will be `UserPrincipal` or `GroupPrincipal` depending on what the actual member is.

But, those `Principal` classes, when they're created, load all the details for that object. So just the act of creating a `UserPrincipal` for a domain user triggers it to go out to the domain and get all the details for the user.

You're better off using [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry) directly, which is what the `AccountManagement` namespace uses in the background anyway. It gives you more control over what's actually happening.

```
var usersGroup = new DirectoryEntry($"WinNT://{Environment.MachineName}/{groupName}");

usersGroup.Invoke("Add", new object[] { $"WinNT://{Environment.MachineName}/{userName}" });
```

This assumes a `userName` variable with the name of the local user. If the user is already in the group, it will throw an exception, so you may want to catch that.

Besides actually working in this case, this will run faster since you're not wasting time collecting details for all the existing members when you have no intention of using any of that data.

*Update:* To read all the members of a local group, use `.Invoke("Members")`. Then you have to create a new `DirectoryEntry` with each member in the collection. For example:

```
foreach (var member in (IEnumerable) usersGroup.Invoke("Members")) {
    using (var memberDe = new DirectoryEntry(member)) {
        Console.WriteLine(memberDe.Name);
    }
}
```

The `DirectoryEntry` class is really a wrapper around the Windows native [ADSI Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/adsi-interfaces). For a group, the underlying object will really be [`IADsGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsgroup). When you call `.Invoke` on a `DirectoryEntry` object, that lets you call the `IADsGroup` methods (you'll see the `Members` method listed in the documentation there). All of the object-specific classes like `IADsGroup` and [`IADsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsuser) all inherit from [`IADs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iads), so the methods from that are usable too.

This only applies to local groups. With Active Directory groups, you don't have to resort to using the `IADs` methods.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. How would I get a list of all the members of a local group? I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: @K4KFH I've updated my answer to include an example for that.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. One suggestion: I would add a note that you need to use the System.Collections namespace. I was already using System.Collections.Generic in my project, so Visual Studio didn't automatically notice the problem, but it gave a confusing error on the IEnumerable cast.

Comment: @K4KFH Yeah, that happens. Visual Studio's intellisense will show you the namespace that needs to be added as a solution to that error.